# How to make textblock content to Hyperlink in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have Email Id in a UWP text-block, how do i make it a "hyperlink" so that when i click on it, it should take me to outlook\email.

Below is the code

```
public string EmailID
{
    get => _emailID;
    set
    {
        _emailID = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EmailID");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource Email}" 
    Text="{Binding List.EmailID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Do i need to use HyperlinkButton instead of Textblock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, below approach helped me to fix

```
<HyperlinkButton    NavigateUri="{Binding List.EmailLink}" 
Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HyperlinkStyle}" Content="{Binding List.Email}" />
```

properties:

```
public string EmailLink {get { return "mailto:" + _email; }set { }}

public string Email {get => _email;set{_email = value;}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HyperLinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/hyperlinks).

Set the `NavigateUri` of the `HyperLink` to the mail uri like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:thisismuzib@gmail.com"> Email me human</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

or probably you can bind it to the backend string provided that the string starts with "mailto:", like this:

```
TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{x:Bind myuri}">Email</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

and int he back end:

`string myuri = "mailto:whatever@outlook.com";`

Comment: This will work if the property you're binding to is a Uri or formatted string.

Comment: nope.. this works fine with normal string provided that, as I said, it starts with **mailto:**. I 've checked.

Comment: Prepending "mailto:" to the beginning of it is formatting. 